# Orange Pi WiringPi

Tags: python, wiringpi, orange-pi

I am using Orange Pi on my project , and I searched for how to control its pin via python and i FOUND some results which suggest to install Wiring Pi 
.I installed WiringPi from https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi and also with pip but in both cases It doesn't work . I get this warning while I tried to use WiringPi:
Unable to determine hardware version. I see: Hardware : sun8i
'- expecting BCM2708 or BCM2709.
If this is a genuino Raspberry pi then please report this
to projects@drogon.net. If this not Raspberry Pi then you 
are on your own as WiringPi is designed to support the
Raspberry PI ONLY.

Comment: The error really says it all: the Orange Pi isn't a Raspberry Pi, and WiringPi is only meant to be used on the latter platform. There _is_ a port to Orange Pi, called [WiringOP](http://www.orangepi.org/Docs/WiringPi.html).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the url that site suggested is blank when I tried to enter there is an error 404

Comment: Can't say I've tried it myself, although I have an Orange Pi myself I kinda gave up on getting it to work with all the GPIO stuff that's meant for RaspPi's

Answer (score 2):

You can find an **Orange Pi** Wiring Pi version through the orangepi official webpage: http://www.orangepi.org/Docs/WiringPi.html

Answer (score 0):

1. download and extract this [OPI-compatible python wrapper](https://github.com/lanefu/WiringPi-Python-OP) (eg. to `/tmp/WiringPi-Python-OP-master`)
2. [download the WiringPI C library](https://github.com/zhaolei/WiringOP/) and extract it inside the `WiringPi` subdir  (eg. to `/tmp/WiringPi-Python-OP-master/WiringPi`)
3. `cd /tmp/WiringPi-Python-OP-master; python setup.py install`

I just tested this on my OrangePI-PC and works pretty well.

([original instructions here, also check if you miss any dependency](https://gist.github.com/lanefu/f16a67195c9fa35c466c6b50cdaeadea)).

Answer (score 0):

you should use the pyH3 library.
you can download this from :
https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
and then install this package

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

extract the (phyh3) folder and place in '/home/pi'
and

```
cd orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3
```

and run `python setup.py install`

The library is now installed.

you can use test code in the folder examples
https://github.com/duxingkei33/orangepi_PC_gpio_pyH3/tree/master/examples